# UI-Router-Breadcrumbs Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, breadcrumbs

I'm working on angular JS app with symfony 2 and i'm trying to modify an existing code. I want to show Breadcrumbs. The Current code :

```
.state('app.marketplace.buyersedit', {
    url: '/buyers/edit/:id',
    templateUrl: '/bundles/ubidelectricity/js/components/Buyer/buyer_form.html',
    title: 'content.list.EDITBUYER',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'content.list.EDITBUYER'
    },
    resolve: loadSequence('BuyerFormCtrl', 'buyerService', 'buyerTypeService', 'countryService', 'languageService', 'regionService', 'userService', 'categoryService', 'languageService', 'ui.select', 'monospaced.elastic', 'touchspin-plugin', 'checklist-model', 'ckeditor-plugin', 'ckeditor')
}).state('app.marketplace.buyersdetails', {
    url: '/buyers/details/:id',
    templateUrl: '/bundles/ubidelectricity/js/components/Buyer/buyer.html',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'content.list.BUYERDETAILS'
    },
    resolve: loadSequence('BuyerCtrl', 'buyerService')
}
```

How can i display Breadcrumbs ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: '{{content.list.BUYERDETAILS}}'
    }
```

make use of brackets instead of just quotes